# Hard refresh and empty cache failing.

Tags: google-chrome

I updated the source code for my html page on a server, but when I refreshed the page in chrome, it didn't update. Then I tried performing a hard refresh and emptying the cache, but it still didn't work. I also tried opening the page in Firefox, which gave me the updated page, but chrome still didn't update the page for another few minutes.

(I'm using Chrome 63 on Windows 7)

Update: it seems that this problem only happens with small files online of at most 5KB or so.

Comment: How did you perform the hard refresh and how did you clear the cache - please provide the steps. Are you sure you have saved the changes before refreshing?

Comment: I opened the devtools and held the refresh button and then selected the "Empty Cache and Hard Reload." Then I opened the settings, opened advanced settings and cleared the cached images and files. Then I tried the  hard reload again. . . and I made sure to save those changes before refreshing.

Comment: Can you reproduce it again (load the page on chrome, make a change, hard-refresh) and can you share the screenshots or short vid w/ dev tools open (networks tab preferably) - any error messages, request headers would be helpful.

Comment: Is there an intermediate proxy server which is caching content? Also, check for the cache headers in the response.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: change the extensions from ".html" to ".php".